# About RequestContext in cefGlue

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

There have multiple cefglue in winform,I hope that each cefglue has a separate cache.

In cefsharp：

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new RequestContextSettings()
{
    CachePath =System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +     @"\Cache\Cache"+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
});
```

I want to know how to do in cefglue

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You should create each browser with own request context (by providing CefRequestContext in CreateBrowser method).

Comment: Hello Dmitry. 
But how is this possible when it's called from a HandleControlSizeChanged of IControl that does not even have a CefRequestContext as a parameter?